# Update Data Validation list when adding a new column to END of Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For some reason my data validation list is not updating when adding a new column to the END of a table. If I had a column in the middle of the table then the data validation list DOES update. I also only want the last 2 columns (so `Header2` and `Header3`) plus any new columns added. My data validations formula is `=INDIRECT("Table3[[#Headers],[Header2]:[Header3]]")`

Before Changes:

[image]

After I add `Test1` and `Test2` columns. As You can see `Test1` is added to the data validation list but `Test2` is not added. I would like `Test2` added to the data validation list as well. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: something like `= OffSet( Table3[#Headers], 0, 1, 1, CountA( Table3[#Headers] ) - 1 )`

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if you use structured references you can create a range name that uses just

```
=Table3[#Headers]
```

in "Refers To" field. Further wrapping in Offset or counting columns is not needed. When a new column is added/inserted, the range name will adjust and the data validation will include the new value.

Comment: This is true, but I didn't want the first column's header appearing in my data validation list.